# Can Googlebot see pagination meta tags created with JavaScript?

Tags: googlebot, javascript, meta-tags, pagination, rel

I would like to render meta pagination links (`<link rel="prev"../>` `<link rel="next"../>`) with JavaScript.

As Google Search Console does not show rendered meta data is there any other way to check if Google bot sees those links or not?

Comment: What is URL you see in your browser when you click on prev or next button, it is changed like domain.com/article/1/ to domain.com/article/2 or something like that?

Comment: What do you mean by "next or prev buttons"? Browser controls? Pagination at the page?

Comment: If you are asking about paginated URLs format I have it is passed via query string (e.g. `p=N` where `N` is the number of a page).

Comment: Yes I am asking your paginated URL format. So what will be your URL when you click on next button. It is like www.example.com/article/2 ?

Comment: `www.example.com/article.html?p=2`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google can *probably* interpret these tags correctly when they are set by JavaScript.   In 2014 [Google announced](https://webmasters.googleblog.com/2014/05/understanding-web-pages-better.html) that it executes JavaScript before indexing pages.

I don't know a good way of testing these tags specifically, however I've seen some testing that indicates Googlebot pays attention to other meta tags when inserted dynamically by JavaScript.

#### [We Tested How Googlebot Crawls Javascript And Here’s What We Learned](http://searchengineland.com/tested-googlebot-crawls-javascript-heres-learned-220157)

> We dynamically inserted in the DOM various tags that are critical for SEO:
>
> - Title elements
> - Meta descriptions
> - Meta robots
> - Canonical tags
>
> Result: In all cases the tags were crawled respected, behaving exactly as HTML elements in source code should.

#### [Dynamically Added Meta Data Indexed By Google Crawlers](https://www.simoahava.com/seo/dynamically-added-meta-data-indexed-google-crawlers/)

> The Meta Description in the SERP result above has been injected with Google Tag Manager. So it IS true:
>
> Google’s crawlers index dynamically injected meta data as well.

I don't see any reason that Googlebot would treat link meta elements for pagination any differently than other dynamically generated meta elements that have been tested.

Answer (score 0):

Your question confuse me.

> Can Googlebot see pagination meta tags created with JavaScript?

Google is pretty smart to execute Javascript from a long time. The best way to know is, test the specific webpage like `www.example.com/article.html?p=2` to fetch and render tools and click on fetch option (by clicking on complete option), then see the source code and see how Googlebot view your content. If there is pagination meta tags then it means Google executing your javascript very well.

Checkout source code of how Googlebot view your page.

[image]

> Is there any other way to check if Google bot sees those links or not?

If you mean by rel or next links, then Go to Search apperence and see HTML improvement option. Google will return duplicate error when two URL display same title for example,

```
www.example.com/page1/ - Hell World - My domain name
www.example.com/page2/ - Hello World - My domain name
```

**So if you have implement pagination correctly then Google will not display the duplicate title error, because pagination pages always have same title across all the pages** like

```
www.example.com/article.html?p=1  - Hell World - My domain name
www.example.com/article.html?p=2  - Hell World - My domain name
```

Comment: There's no way to view the source of a rendered page. All I can see is a set of `<div/>`s with an image like this inside: `<img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAfQAAAAYCAIAAACDRZiQAAAAWklEQVR42u3UMQ0AAADCMPybBh+klbBjKQB3IgGAuQNg7gCYOwDmDoC5A5g7AOYOgLkDYO4AmDuAuQNg7gCYOwDmDoC5A2DuAOYOgLkDYO4AmDsA5g5g7gC8GV+jG5WskWSsAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC" alt="">`

Comment: You can see how Googlebot view your page, and it's source code as well - Go to crawl option - select Fetch as Google option - Enter any URL like `article.html?p=2` then click on fetch and render tools, then click on complete status, and finally [click on fetching option, here is screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RXyxv.png).

Comment: The screenshot you posted is a "Downloaded HTTP response", not a result of browser rendering.

Comment: Can't you see the another box? It show HTTP response code as well source code. I am tired now.